# QT - How to place widgets in mutually exclusive groups?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgroupbox

I'm looking to do something like the following:

example

[image]

But with radio buttons instead of checkboxes. In the above picture widgets are placed into groups which can be enabled/disabled, but I want only 1 group to be enabled at a time (in the example both Group A and Group C are enabled).

I did the above example using [QGroupBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-groupbox-example.html), but it only provides normal checkboxes, not radio buttons as far as I can tell.

Comment: You could explain your scheme better, it's not clear

Comment: @eyllanesc I provided a picture, is that better?

Comment: Do you want the QCheckBox that are in the QGroupBox part to be changed to QRadioButton? If so, why?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want the checkboxes to the left of GroupA / GroupB / etc... to become radiobuttons so I can only toggle one group at a time.

Comment: Okay, you want only one of the groups to be enabled? If so, do I need to be QRadioButtons? I'm telling you because changing the geometry is a more difficult task

Comment: @eyllanesc It's fine if it still looks like a check box, as long as only one of them can be checked at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ckeckbox that appears in the `QGroupBox` is not a `QCheckBox`, it is just a drawing. So a possible solution is to create a class that manages the `QGroupBox` checked.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class ExclusiveManager: public QObject{
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    void addGroupBox(QGroupBox *groupbox){
        if(groupbox){
            groupbox->blockSignals(true);
            groupbox->setChecked(m_groupboxs.isEmpty());
            groupbox->blockSignals(false);
            m_groupboxs << groupbox;
            connect(groupbox, &QGroupBox::toggled, this, &ExclusiveManager::onToggled);
        }
    }
private slots:
    void onToggled(bool on){
        QGroupBox *groupbox = qobject_cast<QGroupBox *>(sender());
        if(on){
            for(QGroupBox *g: m_groupboxs){
                if(g != groupbox && g->isChecked()){
                    g->blockSignals(true);
                    g->setChecked(false);
                    g->blockSignals(false);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            groupbox->blockSignals(true);
            groupbox->setChecked(false);
            groupbox->blockSignals(false);
        }
    }
private:
    QList<QGroupBox *> m_groupboxs;
};

class Widget: public QWidget{
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=nullptr):QWidget(parent){
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);

        ExclusiveManager *manager = new ExclusiveManager(this);

        group_a = new QGroupBox("Group A");
        group_a->setCheckable(true);
        group_b = new QGroupBox("Group B");
        group_b->setCheckable(true);
        group_c = new QGroupBox("Group C");
        group_c->setCheckable(true);
        layout()->addWidget(group_a);
        layout()->addWidget(group_b);
        layout()->addWidget(group_c);

        manager->addGroupBox(group_a);
        manager->addGroupBox(group_b);
        manager->addGroupBox(group_c);

        QVBoxLayout *layA = new QVBoxLayout();
        layA->addWidget(new QLineEdit);
        group_a->setLayout(layA);

        QVBoxLayout *layB = new QVBoxLayout();
        layB->addWidget(new QRadioButton("Option 1"));
        layB->addWidget(new QRadioButton("Option 2"));
        group_b->setLayout(layB);

        QVBoxLayout *layC = new QVBoxLayout();
        layC->addWidget(new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal));
        group_c->setLayout(layC);
    }
private:
    QGroupBox *group_a;
    QGroupBox *group_b;
    QGroupBox *group_c;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: wow thanks, that works perfectly! (I would upvote but I don't have enough rep)

Answer (score 0):

You can link each QGroupBox'toggled signal with the other's setDisabled slot.

ps: I know it's too late but I'm just putting it here if someone else needs it.[image]