# subclassing QGroupBox so that it can be member of QButtonGroup

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qbuttongroup

QButtonGroups can have checkboxes. But you cannot add them to a QButtonGroup because they do not inherit QAbstractButton.

It would be really nice for some UIs to be able to have a few QGroupBoxes with exclusive checkboxes. That is, you check one and the other QGroupBoxes are automatically unchecked.

In an ideal world, I could do something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QGroupBox, QWidget, QApplication, 
                             QAbstractButton, QButtonGroup)

class SuperGroup(QGroupBox, QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super(SuperGroup, self).__init__(title, parent)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setChecked(False)

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        sg1 = SuperGroup(title = 'Super Group 1', parent = self)
        sg1.resize(200,200)
        sg1.move(20,20)

        sg2 = SuperGroup(title = 'Super Group 2', parent = self)
        sg2.resize(200,200)
        sg2.move(300,20)

        self.bgrp = QButtonGroup()
        self.bgrp.addButton(sg1)
        self.bgrp.addButton(sg2)


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 650, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('SuperGroups!')
        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code fails as soon as you try to add a SuperGroup to the button group. PyQt5 explicitly does not support multiple inheritance. But there are some [examples out in the wild, like from this blog](http://trevorius.com/scrapbook/python/pyqt-multiple-inheritance/#comment-193111).

In this simple example, it would be easy to manage the clicks programmatically. But as you add more group boxes, it gets more messy. Or what if you want a QButtonGroup with buttons, check boxes, and group boxes? Ugh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to create a class that inherits from QGroupBox and QAbstractButton (plus it is not possible in pyqt or Qt/C++). The solution is to create a QObject that handles the states of the other QGroupBox when any QGroupBox is checked, and I implemented that for an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51286987/6622587) for Qt/C++ so this answer is just a translation:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QObject, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGroupBox, QWidget, QApplication, QButtonGroup


class GroupBoxManager(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._groups = []

    @property
    def groups(self):
        return self._groups

    def add_group(self, group):
        if isinstance(group, QGroupBox):
            group.toggled.connect(self.on_toggled)
            self.groups.append(group)

    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_toggled(self, state):
        group = self.sender()
        if state:
            for g in self.groups:
                if g != group and g.isChecked():
                    g.blockSignals(True)
                    g.setChecked(False)
                    g.blockSignals(False)

        else:
            group.blockSignals(True)
            group.setChecked(False)
            group.blockSignals(False)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        sg1 = QGroupBox(
            title="Super Group 1", parent=self, checkable=True, checked=False
        )
        sg1.resize(200, 200)
        sg1.move(20, 20)

        sg2 = QGroupBox(
            title="Super Group 2", parent=self, checkable=True, checked=False
        )
        sg2.resize(200, 200)
        sg2.move(300, 20)

        self.bgrp = GroupBoxManager()
        self.bgrp.add_group(sg1)
        self.bgrp.add_group(sg2)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 650, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("SuperGroups!")
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You are an evil genius! It didn't occur to me to make my own version of button group. Your code works great for group boxes, but when I tried to add a radio button or push button, they do not have exclusive behavior.

Comment: To extend this solution so that other checkable widgets can part of a group, you can modify the `if` statement in `add_group` to be `if type(group) in (QGroupBox, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QCheckBox):`.

Comment: @bfris it is better to use `if isinstance(group, (QGroupBox, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QCheckBox)):`

Comment: Yes. Again your solution is better! I was not aware of that syntax for `isinstance`.

Comment: @bfris or more general and short: `if isinstance(group, (QGroupBox, QAbstractButton)):`