# How to tab through all buttons in a tab group?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

It seems by default the Tab method for changing focus through widgets only stops once in a `QButtonGroup` and one is expected to move inside the group with the arrow keys (which only works with radio buttons, anyway). I want, however, to create a button group with `QCheckBox` inside, with the "exclusive" behaviour but allowing to uncheck all boxes, and *where I can use the Tab key to move normally, as if they were not in a group*.

The "clearable" part I could get it done with a subclass, but for the tabbing, it seems as soon as a button in the group gets the focus, it changes the `focusPolicy` for all other buttons such that they don't accept Tab (from 11 to 10), while the button that got the focus changes to 11. How can I disable/override this? Who is messing with the focus policies? I've tried defining a `focusInEvent` method for a `QCheckBox`, and I see that it changes "this button's" `focusPolicy`, but how can I know, from "this button" what the "other buttons" are (given that the final application may have many button groups)? Ideally, I would do something to the `QButtonGroup` subclass, but I don't know if it has any method that can respond to a focus change in its buttons.

Here is a small example. The "Tab order" button prints the current tab order and focus policies:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    


class Custom(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text1, text2):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.box = QCheckBox(text1)
        self.button = QPushButton(text2)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.box)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self._text = f'{text1} {text2}'
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)

    def text(self):
        return self._text


class ClearableButtonGroup(QButtonGroup):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.button = None

    def addButton(self, button):
        try:
            super().addButton(button)
            button.pressed.connect(self.button_pressed)
            button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        except TypeError:
            pass

    def removeButton(self, button):
        try:
            button.pressed.disconnect(self.button_pressed)
            button.clicked.disconnect(self.button_clicked)
            super().removeButton(button)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def button_pressed(self):
        if (self.sender() is self.checkedButton()):
            self.button = self.sender()
        else:
            self.button = None

    def button_clicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        if (button is self.button):
            exclusive = self.exclusive()
            self.setExclusive(False)
            button.setChecked(False)
            self.setExclusive(exclusive)


class HelloWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)          
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)   

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)

        self.box1 = Custom('Box 1', 'Button 1')
        self.box2 = Custom('Box 2', 'Button 2')
        self.box3 = Custom('Box 3', 'Button 3')
        self.box4 = Custom('Box 4', 'Button 4')
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.box1, 0, 0)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.box2, 1, 0)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.box3, 2, 0)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.box4, 3, 0)

        button1 = QPushButton('Tab order')
        gridLayout.addWidget(button1, 4, 1)

        button1.clicked.connect(self.tab)

        group = ClearableButtonGroup(self)
        group.setExclusive(True)
        group.addButton(self.box1.box)
        group.addButton(self.box2.box)
        group.addButton(self.box3.box)
        group.addButton(self.box4.box)

    def tab(self):
        print_tab_order(self)


def print_tab_order(widget):
    w = widget
    while True:
        try:
            print('Text: {}; FocusPolicy: {}'.format(w.text(), w.focusPolicy()))
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        w = w.nextInFocusChain()
        if w == widget:
            break
    print('----')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = HelloWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this behavior is missing, if the QAbstractButton [source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractbutton.cpp?h=5.14) is revised it is implemented:

```cpp
// https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractbutton.cpp?h=5.14#n1088
void QAbstractButton::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    // ...
            d->moveFocus(e->key());
    // ...
```

```cpp
// https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractbutton.cpp?h=5.14#n247
void QAbstractButtonPrivate::moveFocus(int key)
{
    // ...
    if (candidate) {
        if (key == Qt::Key_Up || key == Qt::Key_Left)
            candidate->setFocus(Qt::BacktabFocusReason);
        else
            candidate->setFocus(Qt::TabFocusReason);
    }
}
```

As it is observed, all the buttons are considered as a unit and there is no way to disable it, so a workaround is to implement a class that has the same functionality, and in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61415917/6622587) I implemented it which in your case is:

```py
class ButtonManager(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._buttons = []

    @property
    def buttons(self):
        return self._buttons

    def add_button(self, button):
        if isinstance(button, QtWidgets.QAbstractButton):
            button.toggled.connect(self.on_toggled)
            self.buttons.append(button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_toggled(self, state):
        button = self.sender()
        if state:
            for b in self.buttons:
                if b != button and b.isChecked():
                    b.blockSignals(True)
                    b.setChecked(False)
                    b.blockSignals(False)

        else:
            button.blockSignals(True)
            button.setChecked(False)
            button.blockSignals(False)
```

```py
# ...
button1.clicked.connect(self.tab)

button = ButtonManager(self)
button.add_button(self.box1.box)
button.add_button(self.box2.box)
button.add_button(self.box3.box)
button.add_button(self.box4.box)
# ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure you are answering to my question. I don't care (or at least not as much) about moving with arrow keys, I want to move with Tab. But indeed, looking at the source code I could see a private method of `QAbstractButton` called `fixFocusPolicy`. Bypassing it (e.g. by using `QWidget.focusInEvent` instead of the `QAbstractButton` method, seems to work.

Comment: @Jellby I proposed a workaround (have you tested my solution?) And that does not imply that it is the only solution, so if your new solution works then it is fine

Comment: @eyllanesc Uhm, maybe I'm too tired and I'm missing something but... Is there a purpose of that `button.blockSignals(True)` directly followed by `button.blockSignals(False)`, or is it just a typo?

Comment: @eyllanesc no problem, at least now I know I'm not *that* tired ;-)

Comment: Right, it avoids the issue by not using `QButtonGroup` (and thus the buttons don't know they're in a "group" and `fixFocusPolicy` does nothing). I think your answer was missing this part of the explanation. More seriously, Qt documentation is missing (as far as I can see) any mention of the focus policy messing.